# How do I plot a pandas DataFrame as a table without the index column?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using `pandas.plotting.table` to generate a matplotlib table for my data. The pandas documentation states that if the `rowLabels` kwarg is not specified, it uses the data index. However, I want to plot my data without the index at all. I couldn't find a way to override the setting in the pyplot table either.

Currently my output looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found it easier to bypass `pandas` and to fallback to calling `matplotlib` routines to do the plotting.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = <load your data into a pandas dataframe>

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.keys(), loc='center')
plt.show()
```

See the docs for [ax.table](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.table.html?highlight=table#matplotlib.axes.Axes.table)